# Remove white space form innerHTML string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove white space before and after tags so that I can get the clean HTML using JavaScript:

innerHTML String (while I print on console):

```
"
                    <p>There are <i>many variations </i>of passages of <b>Lorem</b> Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some formThere are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form.</p>

                "
```

While trying with following:

```
function htmlCleanUp(html) {
        if (html) {
            return html.replace(/>\s+|\s+</g, function (m) {
                return m.trim();
            });
        }
    }
```

It removes inner tag white space, but I want to remove white space only before and after the tag.

Comment: Why not `return html.trim();`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - while not in the OP, `html.trim()` would not account for multiple outer elements (removing the spaces in between them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the DOM to help sort through outer elements while leaving the inner tags alone. To extend your example, I added another outer tag to the `incoming_html` string with spaces in between.

```js
let incoming_html = "                                       <p>There are <i>many variations </i>of passages of <b>Lorem</b> Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some formThere are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form.</p>       <div>another passage</div> ";


function htmlCleanUp(html) {
  console.log("Before transformation:", html);
  const testbed = document.getElementById('testbed');
  testbed.innerHTML = html;
  let sets = document.querySelectorAll("#testbed > *")
  let out = [];
  for (let set in sets) {
    out.push(sets[set].outerHTML)
  }
  testbed.innerHTML = "";
  return out.join("").trim();
}


console.log("After transformation:", htmlCleanUp(incoming_html));
```

```css
#testbed {
  visible: hidden;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id='testbed'></div>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: set is not defined

Comment: @DanielSmith - I updated my answer, should take care of that

Comment: I have an another JS question, It would be helpfull if you could take a look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737245/javascript-add-line-break-after-specefic-character-count-with-maximum-line-lim

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
const regex = /\s*<\s*/gm;
const str = ` <p>There are <i>many variations </i>of passage`;
const subst = `<`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

const regex2 = /\s*>s*/gm;
const subst2 = `>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result2 = result.replace(regex2, subst2);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result2);
```